# Can you run Adobe Premiere Pro on Linux Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a friend that need to use  Adobe Premiere Pro on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adobe hasn't made version for Linux, the only way to do it would be to use Windows version through [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Unfortunately though, [the results aren't the best](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=128).

I would rather suggest finding alternative to Premiere, dual booting or using virtual machine.